# C++ deconstructor message not shown

Tags: c++, destructor

> When executing the following code the constructor messages for both objects
>   appear, but the destructor messages appear only for the 'hattie' object. 
>   Weren't destructors for both objects run on exit?  Note that the base class destructor is protected, satisfying Sutter's rule #4.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Pup {
protected:
    string name ;
    ~Pup() {cout << "bye " + name << endl;}
};

class Corgi : public Pup {
public:
    Corgi(string name) {this->name = name ;
        cout << "hello " + name << endl;}
    ~Corgi() {cout << "bye-bye " + name << endl;}
};

int main() {
    Corgi hattie("Hattie");
    Corgi* gus = new Corgi("Gus");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You used `new` without `delete`.

Comment: You never call `delete gus;` so what do you expect?

Comment: when you use `new` you **must** use `delete` sometime afterwards.

Comment: Not strictly true, guys; if you change the stmt creating hattie as shown below, the destructor for hattie is run on exit without calling delete.               
    Corgi hattie = *(new Corgi("Hattie"));

Comment: C++ ain't Java innit. You need to call the destructor yourself. Use delete explicitly or, better still, a smart pointer type. Also the Pup destructor ought to be marked virtual.

Comment: @user3150422: That’s the destructor for another `Corgi`; you copied it.

Comment: OT: ~Pup() should be virtual.